# Front USB Ports Not Detected

Tags: usb, hardware

I've searched on this website and it doesn't seem like there have been many answers on this. On the windows 10 OS, the front USB ports were being detected, but in Ubuntu, it isn't. Some help?

Here is my output:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 3938:1031  
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:0100 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 003: ID 2357:012d  
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
System:    Kernel: 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.5.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu1) dm: gdm3
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: MSI model: 970 GAMING (MS-7693) v: 4.0 serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: V22.3 date: 05/12/2015`
```

Comment: Add to your post the output of `lsusb; inxi -SM -xx -! 31 -y 80`. Run `watch -d lsusb` and plug/unplug a USB device there, do you see any changes? If the answer is _yes_ add that difference to the post.

Comment: Model of the PC or Motherboard? It's possible the Front Panel USB is being driven from a different USB Controller on the Motherboard and that driver is missing on the Ubuntu side.

Comment: @PabloBianchi information added. It doesn't detect the FRONT, after plugging in the device.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by adding ioommu=soft on the GRUB entry.